# How to display the selection of a ComboBox with a list fetched from a database in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox which the ItemSource is binded to a List of `ESTADO`, a entity in my project. The ComboBox look like this:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Visibility="{Binding EstadoComboBox}" Name="CatalogoEstados" DisplayMemberPath="NOMBRE" SelectedValuePath="NOMBRE" SelectedValue="{Binding Estado}" ItemsSource="{Binding Estados}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SeleccionarEstadoCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CatalogoEstados, Path=SelectedItem.ID}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

When I select a item in the ComboBox, the property `NOMBRE` of the object `ESTADO` who is a string is assigned to a variable of type string named `Estado`.

Somethimes I want the variable `Estado` to be assigned from the constructor like this:

```
Estado = pplDatosGenerales.ESTADO;
```

`pplDatosGenerales.ESTADO` is a string with the string item previously select in the ComboBox, but when I assign the variable from the constructor, the ComboBox view is not showing the item selected, the variable is assigned correctly but in the view the ComboBox appears empty as if I haven't selected anything. Why is this happening and how can I solve this? I want the ComboBox to show the value that the variable `Estado` has.

Comment: just create a model that contains your "display string" and your "value" and bind it to the combo box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the value of Estado was not in the ComboBox ItemSource. Once I debugged the project and saw the value of Estado was not included in the ItemSource.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to post more of your code. You've set `SelectedValuePath` to NOMBRE...if NOMBRE is a string then your `SelectedValue` type should be a string too, but you're instead binding it to a view model property called Estado? In which case Estado should be a string too, and in your constructor you would instead do `Estado = pplDatosGenerales.ESTADO.NOMBRE'.

I suspect the problem here is simply the `SelectedValuePath` setting. Remove it, and you'll probably find that this all starts working as you intend.

Comment: Indeed, NOMBRE is a string and I assign the string value of the item selected from the ComboBox to the string variable Estado,  and in the constructor I assign Estado the value of pplDatosGenerales.NOMBRE that is a string too. I removed the SelectedValuePath from the control and still showing null when I assign Estado from the constructor.

Comment: SelectedValuePath is for assign the property NOMBRE of the object ESTADO to the variable estado, and not assign all the object as string like this "NAMEOFTHEPROJECT.MODEL.ESTADO"

Comment: That should be working then, does your `Estado` property support INPC?